# Are non-islamic answer acceptable in this SE community?

Tags: discussion, scope

Some of the questions presented here (like "Should I do ..." ) can be answered in more than one perspectives. Like some questions can be answered in a religion independent manner.

For example, the question [regarding having sex with slave and trade of slave](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77068/can-a-master-sell-his-slave-after-having-intercourse-with-her), my commonsensical answer would be a 'No, any other person shouldn't captivate another person as a slave at any condition, and sex should be only upon consent'. However, these acts may be permissible to some extent according to the islamic literature as said in [existing answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77068/can-a-master-sell-his-slave-after-having-intercourse-with-her/77069#77069)

My question is; does this site accept both kind of answers? or only second kind of answer (what islamic literature says about it) is permissible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are not an advice forum. Most "What should I do..." type questions are a poor fit for the site, period.

The entire purpose of this site is to spread knowledge on the topic of Islam, so answering any such question from a perspective that has nothing to do with the topic of Islam is just noise.

Answer (score -2):

There is another approach to this sort of question - that is to distinguish between the historical and the universal in Islam, as scholar Fazlur Rahman proposed. Slavery is a good example - slavery is universally legally and morally impermissible nowadays and sex without consent is a sexual abuse crime. However at the time of the prophet slavery and sex with slave women was an historical and apparently accepted fact. Lets regard it as an historical artifact and agree to move on.

So Islamic scholars have the option of responding "Islam has no answer to this question" as goldPseudo above might do, or offering an opinion based on deep knowledge of Islam and consideration of ethical issues in society.